# Discord JS v13 Reaction Collector not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been trying for a really long time to make it work, I tried the await version too but none of them collect the reactions. The collector completes its cycle, but then it shows that no reaction was collected.

```
        if (command == 'react') {

        const filter = (reaction,user) => {
            return user.id === message.author.id;
        }
        
        const collector = message.createReactionCollector({
            filter,
            max: 1,
            time: 1000 * 5,
        })

        collector.on('collect',(reaction) =>{
            console.log(reaction.emoji);
        })

        collector.on('end',(collected) =>{
            console.log(collected);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if you bot have the `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intent activated, you need it to make the collector work

Comment: Thanks! This worked right away!